# Multicolor for citites in geopandas

Tags: python, matplotlib, geopandas, cartopy

I am able to read shape file using geopandas but i want to color the different cities with different color of one state , How i can color different color to different cities of one state ?
Thank you.

```
        import geopandas as gpd

       gf_states = gpd.read_file('IND_adm2.shp')
gr_states.head()
    ID_0    ISO     NAME_0  ID_1    NAME_1  ID_2    NAME_2  TYPE_2  ENGTYPE_2   NL_NAME_2   VARNAME_2   geometry
0   105     IND     India   1   Andaman and Nicobar     1   Andaman Islands     District    District    None    None    MULTIPOLYGON (((93.64841 14.93487, 93.64917 14...
1   105     IND     India   1   Andaman and Nicobar     2   Nicobar Islands     District    District    None    None    MULTIPOLYGON (((92.78778 9.24417, 92.78889 9.2...
2   105     IND     India   2   Andhra Pradesh  3   Anantapur   District    District    None    Anantpur, Ananthapur    POLYGON ((77.69000 15.17628, 77.69378 15.17347...
3   105     IND     India   2   Andhra Pradesh  4   Chittoor    District    District    None    Chitoor|Chittor     POLYGON ((78.47611 13.93680, 78.48208 13.93007...
4   105     IND     India   2   Andhra Pradesh  5   Cuddapah    District    District    None    None    POLYGON ((78.94612 15.19465, 78.95062 15.18535...
```

---

**Here suppose i want to color NAME_2 ( Anantapur with color red, chittor with color blue and cuddapah with color yellow and so on of one state NAME_1 Andhra Pradesh ) . How i can do this ?
Thank you.**
Code on which i am working on it below :-

```
def fig_beauty_hires(ax,xlim=[66,78],ylim=[20,24],st_name,states=False,states_name=False):


import cartopy as crs
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
from cartopy.mpl.gridliner import LONGITUDE_FORMATTER, LATITUDE_FORMATTER
import geopandas as gpd

gf_states = gpd.read_file('IND_adm2.shp')
gdff = gf_states.loc[gf_states['NAME_1']==st_name,['geometry','NAME_2']]

if states_name:
    gf_new = gdff.cx[xlim[0]:xlim[1],ylim[0]:ylim[1]]
    state_points = gf_new.geometry.apply(lambda x :x.representative_point().coords[:])
    state_coords = [point[0] for point in state_points]

    cMap = ['#00FF00','#FFFF00','#00FFFF','#FF00FF','#FF4500','#7B68EE','#ADFF2F']
    for name, coord , col,j in zip(gf_new.NAME_2,state_coords,cMap,range(0,len(cMap))):
        #print(name)
        #ax.add_geometries(gdff.geometry,crs=ccrs.PlateCarree(),color=cMap[j],edgecolor='k')

        if name=="Nashik" or name=="Aurangabad"or name=="Jalna" or name=="Osmanabad"or name=="Gadag"or name=="Bellary"or                            name=="Mysore" or name=="Davanagere" or name=="Hassan" or name=="Greater Bombay"or name=="Thiruvananthapuram"or                          name=="Alappuzha" or name=="Kollam" or name=="Pattanamtitta" or name=="Idukki" or name=="Palakkad":
            print("if j:",str(cMap[j]))
            ax.add_geometries(gdff.geometry,crs=ccrs.PlateCarree(),facecolor=cMap[j],edgecolor='k')
            ax.text(x=coord[0],y=coord[1],s=" ",horizontalalignment='center',fontweight='normal',fontsize=10,color='k')

        else:
            print("else j:",str(cMap[j]))
            ax.add_geometries(gdff.geometry,crs=ccrs.PlateCarree(),facecolor=cMap[j],edgecolor='k')
            ax.text(x=coord[0],y=coord[1],s=name,horizontalalignment='center',fontweight='bold',fontsize=10,color='k')
if __name__=="__main__":
    import cartopy.crs as ccrs
    import cartopy.feature as cfeature

    from cartopy.mpl.gridliner import LONGITUDE_FORMATTER, LATITUDE_FORMATTER                

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(19.20,10.80), subplot_kw={'projection': ccrs.PlateCarree()})  
    fig_beauty_hires(ax=ax)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear, what is the final output that you expect. And the code you posted doesn't run (even when we ignore the multiple imports, etc.).

My understanding is that you want to plot some geometries where you want to be able to control the `facecolor` for each geometry. Here is a simple snippet that you can build on: (I managed to find a dataset that matches the one you posted.)

```
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from cartopy.feature import ShapelyFeature

# Obtain the data & keep only relevant attributes
states = gpd.read_file('gadm36_IND.gpkg', layer=1)[['NAME_1', 'NAME_2', 'geometry']]

# Prepare the data for easy manipulations later
df = states[states.NAME_1 == 'Andhra Pradesh']
df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True) #for later convenience

# Prepare the projections
data_crs = ccrs.PlateCarree() # this will be fixed by your data
proj_crs = ccrs.PlateCarree() # this determines the projection of the plot
extents = [75, 86, 12, 20] # change as needed depending on the data

# Produce the main figure and axis
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 15))
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection=proj_crs)

# Some configuration
ax.set_extent(extents, crs=data_crs)
ax.coastlines() # just for (some) spatial reference only

# Plot the geometries. A very basic plotting scheme shown here
colours = ['red', 'green', 'yellow'] # (almost) randomly selected
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    sp = ShapelyFeature(row.geometry, data_crs,
                        edgecolor='k', linewidth=0.5,
                        facecolor=colours[index%len(colours)])
    ax.add_feature(sp)
    locxy = row.geometry.representative_point()
    ax.annotate(row.NAME_2, xy=(locxy.x, locxy.y)) # use transform for other projections

plt.show()
```

[The resulting plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuv8g.png)